# How are the speed limits set in osm2po?

Tags: openstreetmap, osm2po

Using osm2po I found a problem. In the configuration file "osm2po.config" I can set the various values ​​of speed limits for each road type but for example for this type of street (wtr.tag.highway.motorway = 1, 11, 120) in the output file the speed limit for that type of road is set to 110 instead of 120. Why is that?

I also wanted to know if openstreetmap provides data on speed limits for each road and if it is true, is there a way to insert them into the output file osm2po?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a closer look into the config.
This should answer both questions:

```
#wtr.maxSpeedOverrides = false
```

Comment: Thanks but in my old version of osm2po.config there isn't this string. (osm2po-4.5.25).

Comment: yes, this parameter has been introduced in 4.6.9

Comment: Then in previous versions the values ​​for the speed limits were not overwritten by default. is it correct?

Comment: no, they were / are overwritten by default if osm2po finds an osm-maxSpeed-tag. But sometimes this behavior is not wanted (bike-routing e.g.). Therefore I introduced it.